# Can <link rel=preload> preload resources inside <iframe>s?

Tags: html, performance, preload

I have a page that embeds another page, let’s call it `frame.html`:

```html
<iframe src="sub-page.html">
```

On `sub-page.html`, it loads some CSS and an image:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sub-page.css">
<img src="sub-page.svg" alt="Sub-Page">
```

I at first thought that I could speed up the loading of these sub-subresources by adding `<link rel=preload>` to `frame.html`:

```html
<link rel="preload" href="sub-page.css" as="style">
<link rel="preload" href="sub-page.svg" as="image">
```

…but that doesn’t seem to help, looking at the resulting waterfall graphs.

The specs for preload links seem to emphasize that it’s only for subresources *of the current page*, but since you can preload font files that are called from a stylesheet, it’s plausible that resources of a frame could also count. Am I missing something, like the correct use of the `crossorigin` attribute?

Comment: What browsers did you test?

Comment: @rustyx Turns out I was looking at an outdated CDN cache. This totally works, I’ll answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes.

Turns out I was looking at an old, unpurged version of the page when I was trying my performance tests.

**`<link rel=preload>` absolutely can preload subresources of an `<iframe>`’d page.**.

Comment: Are you sure this is working for you? I'm trying to do exactly the same thing and it's not working for me. I can see the request twice in the Network tab of the browser. Do you have a full working example?

Comment: Sure: https://contrast-o-vision.ti.gt/ — I maybe should have specified this is a _same-origin_ `iframe`, which is not typical usage.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately though, as far as I can see, it's not working at least on my browser? I'm using Microsoft Edge 93 (which is Chromium based). I'm getting the following message: The resource https://contrast-o-vision.ti.gt/css/intro.css was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

Comment: Looks like I have `<!-- Do these work? -->` in the source, so clearly back then I wasn’t certain either. Unmarked as “answered”

Comment: This does not appear to be working. On your page I can see that `intro.css` was loaded twice. Additionally, I get warnings in the console: `The resource ... was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.`